# MongoDb Select Query Issue Whit Regular Expression (Starts whit and Ends Whit)

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need a regular expression to validate a String like this:

1678;1678;1678;1678 and 1;0;1;1;0;1

I tried to use this pattern:

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find(
    {
    "magnitude": /^[1678][1678]$/,
    "flag": /^[1][1]$/
    }
)
```

but it doesnt works, i try this two patterns that works separate but not both at the same time

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find(
    {
        "magnitude": /[1678]$/,
        "flag": /[1]$/
    }
)

db.getCollection('CollectionName').find(
    {
       "magnitude": /^[1678]/,
       "flag": /^[1]/
    }
)
```

I didnt find any character like * in SQL to use in this

I am using robomongo 1.0.0 for querys

I will apreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: try `/^1678$/` `/^[01]$/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match more than one `;` separated strings then  use capturing groups.

```
db.getCollection('CollectionName').find(
    {
       "magnitude": /^1678(;1678)*$/,
       "flag": /^[01](;[01])*$/
    }
)
```

`(;1678)*` matches the string `;1678`, zero or more times.

`[01]` matches either `0` **OR** `1`

Comment: I don't know that we use `;` in the query or not. If so then try or `/^1678(;1678)*$/`, `/^[01](;[01])*$/`

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it works, the proposed solution of your comment