# Java Spring Boot Json Query With Regular Expression In MongoDb

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I need to do this query in spring boot: [MongoDb Select Query Issue Whit Regular Expression (Starts whit and Ends Whit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651173/mongodb-select-query-issue-whit-regular-expression-starts-whit-and-ends-whit)

I will explain my intentions: i want to search in the DDBB whit a regular expression (end whit and starts whit) the fields Valores and Flag

This is the code of the method of my repository:

```
@Query("{'Valores': { $regex: ?0$, $regex: ^?1} ,'Flag': { $regex: ^?2, $regex: ?3$}}")
List<Curvas> encontrarCurvasPorPattern(String valorInicio,String valorFinal,String flagInicio,String flagFinal);
```

I try many querys like this:

```
@Query("{'Valores': {$regex: ^[0](;[01])*$} ,'Flag': { $regex: ^[0](;[01])*$}}")
```

But it doesnt works

Here the Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbMascotaApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'curvasRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'Valores': { $regex: "_param_0"$, $regex: ^"_param_1"} ,'Flag': { $regex: ^"_param_2", $regex: "_param_3"$}}
                                ^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at es.cic.cmunoz.MongoDbMascotaApplication.main(MongoDbMascotaApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'curvasRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'Valores': { $regex: "_param_0"$, $regex: ^"_param_1"} ,'Flag': { $regex: ^"_param_2", $regex: "_param_3"$}}
                                ^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'Valores': { $regex: "_param_0"$, $regex: ^"_param_1"} ,'Flag': { $regex: ^"_param_2", $regex: "_param_3"$}}
                                ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:301) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:272) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:263) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery$ParameterBindingParser.parseAndCollectParameterBindingsFromQueryIntoBindings(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:230) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.<init>(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.StringBasedMongoQuery.<init>(StringBasedMongoQuery.java:72) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:169) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:117) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

And here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.user</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoDbMascota</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MongoDbMascota</name>
    <description>MongoDbMascota</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

in adition i put my java class for the mapping:

```
@Document(collection = "CollectionName")
public class Curvas {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field("Id Curva")
    private int idCurva;
    @Field("Cups")
    private String cups;
    @Field("Magnitud")
    private int magnitud;
    @Field("Fecha")
    private String fecha;
    @Field("Valores")
    private String valores;
    @Field("Flag")
    private String flag;

    public Curvas() {

    }
    // omited getters setters and toString() To abreviate
}
```

i was watching this documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#d0e3309

SOLVED the correct query is:

```
@Query("{'Valores': { $regex: '?0$', $regex: '^?1'} ,'Flag': { $regex: '^?2', $regex: '?3$'}}")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try escaping the '$'... maybe `\$` or `\\$`

Comment: Sorry but it does not work

Comment: The JSON query is not well formed. We can see the root cause `JSONParseException`. Is it possible to include that `$` along with the param so that the final json will be like `{
 'Valores': {
  $regex: "_param_0$",
  $regex: "^_param_1"
 },
 'Flag': {
  $regex: "^_param_2",
  $regex: "_param_3$"
 }
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! it works i only need to change the " of your code to ' and it works in my question i will edit the question whit the correct query put your comment as an answer to close this question , Thanks again !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  actually also provide options for your regular expression, like this:

```
@Query(value = "{'title': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
Foo findByTitleRegex(String regexString);
```

The `i` option makes the query case-insensitive.